# Programatically turn on properties serialization on .NET EF Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have my data modeled with CodeFirst on EF 6.
I'm building a Web API to which different type of clients would have access but depending on the client´s configuration they should see or not certain properties of the models.

¿How do I turn on or off the `[JsonIgnore]` or `[serialized]`? Is it possible to set a certain set of rules to do this, like a validator?

Comment: How do you get the json representation of your models?

Comment: JsonMediaTypeFormatter
```config.Formatters.Clear();
    config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(); ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: Using a custom ContractResolver

You can create a custom contract resolver and use it when creating the response:

```
public class TestContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public string ExcludeProperties { get; set; }
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type,
                                           MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ExcludeProperties))
            return base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization)
                        .Where(x => !ExcludeProperties.Split(',').Contains(x.PropertyName))
                        .ToList();

        return base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
    }
}
```

here is the usage:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Test()
{
    var person = new Person() { Id = 1, FirstName = "x", LastName = "y", Age = 20 };
    string excludeProperties= "FirstName,Age";
    string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.None,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        ContractResolver = new TestContractResolver() 
                        { 
                            ExcludeProperties = excludeProperties
                        }
                    });
    var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(result, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return response;
}
```

And the result would be:

```
{"Id":1,"LastName":"y"}
```

### Option 2: Using Dictionary

You can have a comma separated string of property names to ignore, then select properties and put them (name and value) in a dictionary and use them as result:

```
[HttpGet]
public Dictionary<string, Object> Test()
{
    var person = new Person() { Id = 1, FirstName = "x", LastName = "y", Age = 20 };

    string excludeProperties = "FirstName,Age";
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
    person.GetType().GetProperties()
          .Where(x => !excludeProperties.Split(',').Contains(x.Name)).ToList()
          .ForEach(p =>
          {
              var key = p.Name;
              var value = p.GetValue(person);
              dictionary.Add(key, value);
          });

    return dictionary;
}
```

And the result would be:

```
{"Id":1,"LastName":"y"}
```

Comment: I was thinking of a way of using data annotations but I think using an object of excluded properties serialized into the user claims and then pass this as a string to the contract would be a cleaner solution. I had forgotten that existed such a thing as contractResolver. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Thanks again :D